# Crystal Report in vb.net application showing blank page

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report that works in Crystal Reports Writer XI just fine.  I run the report in the application passing the same information that I use to test in the CR Writer and the report is completely blank.  No exceptions what so ever are raised in the application.

I've opened the report in VS2008 and resaved it and verified the database and still nothing.  I have two different versions of the report.  The report is using stored Procs and I have verified that it is loading the report because it is accepting the parameters I setup in the report.  If I change the name of the parameter I'm saving to something invalid it then throws an error.

This is a very weird issue I have not experienced in the past.

Comment: are you sure it's accessing the correct report? Try displaying a parameter on the report.

Comment: What do you mean by "blank"? Is it a report with no data? Is it just a blank white page showing in the crv? maybe post the code that is loading the report and passing it to the viewer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue ended up being the report file being corrupt.  Recreated the report and it worked fine.